# 正々堂々勝負して's meaning

Tags: expressions

In [this anime trailer](https://youtu.be/2supSiC27XU?t=28) the protagonist say this sentence:

> **正々堂々勝負して**、あ、みやがれってんだ！

I can't figure out the meaning... Is maybe something like "Fight like a man!" or "Don't play rough!"?

PS: here the [context scene.](https://youtu.be/tXeBkgiBTac?t=3m26s)

Comment: So do you already know what [正々堂々](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%AD%A3%E3%80%85%E5%A0%82%E3%80%85) is? And do you understand what this あ is doing?

Comment: No. I was not sure about its meaning.

Comment: I mean, its literally meaning is "Do victory or defeat in fair and square way". It sound a little bit strange for me. "あ、みやがれってんだ" I suppose that Galo is saying something like " [...] because you seems poor to me/you make me laugh".

Comment: Next time please try to explain your problem in more detail. The full translation attempt will greatly help to make a sufficient answer. The true source of your confusion often exists outside of what you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry but... VVayfarer understood without problems my question. So, It was done correctly.

Comment: VVayfarer's [initial answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/68417/1) was (understandably) very short. From the timestamp, I think it was only after you posted your translation attempt ("do victory" and "seems poor") that he realized you had gotten many parts wrong and he needed to elaborate.

Comment: The first Wayfarer's answer was enough thorough: it was possibile because he undestood my question. In other words, he gave me the answer already when he wrote the first version's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fight like a man!" is more or less exactly what it means in this context.

More generally, it could mean something to the effect of "fight/play fair and square" or "fight/play without resorting to cowardly/underhanded means" etc. Here, the speaker seems to refer to the fact that the sitting guy is making the other two fight in his stead.

To break it down a bit more:

- 正々堂々 means "fair and square", "without resorting to
  cowardly/underhanded means". "Like a man" is a very faithful
  translation in this context.
- 勝負する means "to fight", "to compete", "to play (competitively)" etc.
- ～てみやがれ！ (from ～てみろ) would literally mean "try to (x)!" or "how about you (x)!". In some contexts you would translate this, e.g.「この一撃に耐えてみやがれ」~ "(Go ahead,) try to withstand this attack." In
  this context, you could translate it as "Try fighting like a man!" or
  "How about fighting like a man!". Still, this sounds noticeably more literal (and clunky) in 
  English.
- ～ってんだ kind of has a similar vibe as adding "(...), is what I'm saying" to
  the end of a statement, or starting a sentence with "I'm telling you
  ~". So the sentence would even more literally become something like
  "How about fighting like a man, is what I'm saying!" or "I'm telling
  you to try fighting like a man!". However, the Japanese meaning is
  much less literal than this / mainly modifies the nuance, so
  these too would normally be lost in translation.

Comment: and what is the みやがれってんだ ? variant of ～やがる?

Comment: It’s from 正々堂々勝負してみろ　→　正々堂々勝負してみやがれ（みやがる）. A more literal translation would therefore be more like “Try fighting like a man!”. Or maybe “How about fighting like a man!” (but this sounds a bit off to me since in English it’s in the form of a rhetorical “question”). Then with the ～ってんだ it would become something like “I’m telling you to fight (/”try fighting”) like a man!”, but it doesn't really work (at least as well) in English.

Comment: Oh! So it's not the "miru" of the verb "to see", but the "miru" for "try to". Mmh, now it have more sense to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah so the ってんだ in this case is short for と言っているんだ? So we could rephrase it as 正々堂々と勝負してみろと(俺が)言っているんだ。Is that what you mean?

Comment: @kandyman In theory, kind of, but in practice, this type of usage often only modifies the nuance and doesn’t have the literal meaning of って言ってるんだ (the effect is a bit similar though), so you couldn’t really rephrase it like that. This more precisely stems from と言うのだ, although this would be even more incompatible with the context. Maybe “Fight like a man, is what I’m saying!” or something _could_ work to convey it… or maybe not…

Comment: Yes I understand the tone is wrong, but I was asking more about the grammar than the meaning.

Comment: @kandyman Ok, I guess I misunderstood then. If you just want to convert it to a more standard form,「正々堂々勝負してみろと言うのだ」would be its equivalent.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense